# how do I parse a tcpdump file with python

Tags: python, parsing, tcp, tcpdump

I have a tcpdump file that I would like to parse. The tcpdump file looks like this

```
23:31:54.380799 IP 192.140.3.20.38373 > 240.240.255.250.8082: UDP, length 542
```

I want to parse the file to get the source ip, destination ip and the total size of the packet and store it into a list.

How can I get the output to look something like this:

```
[192.140.3.20.38,240.240.255.250.80,542]
```

Comment: I think you need regex for this..

Comment: @Ted Brown: Check answer and provide feedback

Comment: Your example output isn't just the IP address - what are the '.38' and '.80' bits on the end?

Comment: @Ted Brown: Check the answer and provide feedback

Answer (score 1):

[pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is often overlooked as a way of writing parsers that can be highly readable — quickly.

In this case `time` represents the grammatical element at the beginning of each tcpdump line. `address` represents each of the TCP addresses. `pp.Literal` is used variously to present particles such as 'IP' and '>', for instance. I've used the `suppress` method to omit items that are unneeded from output.

The file that I have processed is your line repeated about ten times with only the final constant incremented in each line.

```
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> time = pp.Word(pp.nums + '.:')
>>> address = pp.Word(pp.nums + '.')
>>> line = time.suppress() + pp.Literal('IP').suppress() + address + pp.Literal('>').suppress() + address + pp.Literal(':').suppress() + pp.Literal('UDP,').suppress() + pp.Literal('length').suppress() + pp.Word(pp.nums)
>>> with open('temp.txt') as lines:
...     for a_line in lines:
...         print (line.parseString(a_line).asList())
...         
['192.140.3.20.38373', '240.240.255.250.8082', '542']
['192.140.3.20.38373', '240.240.255.250.8082', '543']
['192.140.3.20.38373', '240.240.255.250.8082', '544']
['192.140.3.20.38373', '240.240.255.250.8082', '545']
['192.140.3.20.38373', '240.240.255.250.8082', '546']
['192.140.3.20.38373', '240.240.255.250.8082', '547']
['192.140.3.20.38373', '240.240.255.250.8082', '548']
['192.140.3.20.38373', '240.240.255.250.8082', '549']
['192.140.3.20.38373', '240.240.255.250.8082', '550']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using regex. Try below

```
#Take the value in a string
string = """23:31:54.380799 IP 192.140.3.20.38373 > 240.240.255.250.8082: UDP, length 542"""

#import regular expression module
import re



#Retrieve source and destination ip
output = re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", string)

#packet size
output.append(re.sub(r'.*length(.*)',r'\1',string))

#required info is in output


print output
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a regex:

```
import re
data = "23:31:54.380799 IP 192.140.3.20.38373 > 240.240.255.250.8082: UDP, length 542\n" * 2
print(re.findall(r"[^ ]* IP (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).\d+ > (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).\d+:.*, length (\d+)", data))
```

Output:

```
[('192.140.3.20', '240.240.255.250', '542'),
 ('192.140.3.20', '240.240.255.250', '542')]
```

(I've made the output match the description, rather than exactly match your example output which I didn't understand fully).